# Verificar smartphone na horizontal

Tags: android, delphi

Como verificar em uma determinada situação se o *smartphone* está na horizontal?

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar a seguinte estratégia:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

E o resultado será conforme a documentação que está [aqui](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation).
Porém, já vi algumas pessoas reclamando dessa forma de verificar, dizem que não é confiável, e podes usar um serviço do android:

```
public String getRotation(Context context){
    final int rotation = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();
           switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                return "portrait";
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                return "landscape";
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                return "reverse portrait";
            default:
                return "reverse landscape";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Carlos, consegui fazer da seguinte maneira, no evento onResize do form, verificando se a largura é maior que altura.

Answer (score 1):

vi seu comentario e voce que saber usando as medidas , essa maneira que o Carlos Bridi postou e muito boa , mas se voce que usando medidas ai vc pode usar esse codigo abaixo:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get the display metrics
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;

        boolean isLandscape = width > height;
    }
}
```

ai vc checa se o width for maior que height o device esta em landscape mode que seria a horizontal , nesse caso usei uma boolean mas tem varias maneiras de fazer , acho que o melhor seria fazer uma method pra isso , tipo :

```
public boolean isLandscape()
{
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    return (metrics.widthPixels>metrics.heightPixels);
}
```